# A complex integral over two lines?

Tags: complex-integration

Let C denote the union of segments $[-1-i,2]$ and $[2,3+2i]$. Find

$$\int_{c}(z^{2}-z+1)dz$$

Sorry about not showing any work. I know we are supposed to parameterize the lines but I'm have a lot of difficulty with that.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Argand diagram?

Comment: @DHMO I am not familiar with that diagram

Comment: It's where you use a 2D plane to represent complex numbers, except that the x-axis represents the real part and the y-axis represents the imaginary part. You can use that to draw a straight line and find its equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you how to parametrise the line from $-1-i$ to $2$. There are lots of ways of parametrising it actually, and it doesn't matter which one we choose. One simple example is:
$$ z = (-1-i)(1-t) + 2t, \ \ \ \ \ 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$
Hopefully you can convince yourself that this works.

Having done this, you can write the integral in terms of the parameter $t$:
$$z^2 - z + 1 = \left[(-1-i)(1-t) + 2t\right]^2 - \left[(-1-i)(1-t) + 2t\right] + 1$$
(Of course, you could simplify this if you wish...)

You should also write $dz$ in terms of $t$, using the chain rule.
$$ dz = \left(-(-1-i)+2\right)dt$$

Finally, put everything together, taking care to put the correct limits on the integral:
$$ \int_{[-1-i,2i]}(z^2 - z + 1)dz = \int_{0}^{1} \left( \left[(-1-i)(1-t) + 2t\right]^2 - \left[(-1-i)(1-t) + 2t\right] + 1 \right) \times \left(-(-1-i)+2\right)dt $$
(Again, this will look much nicer once you simplify everything!)

Comment: Is there a typo? "the line from $−1−i$ to $2\color{red}{i}$"

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed it!